# Is there anyway I can make a Discord js Bot that send an embed when a specific account in instagram posts

Tags: discord.js, instagram

i just want it to send an embed or even just the link of the post when the account posts on Instagram. I tried the IFTTT website but they only let you do this for your own instagram account and i want it to do the above for another public account. Thenks.

Comment: Share the code that you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that coding the entire project out for you would be useful, so I can give you some pointers:
For the Instagram scraping, I'd suggest using [Nightmare](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare), a high-level browser automation library. It's easy to use and quite powerful.
Here's what the start of your program should look like:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const Nightmare = require('nightmare')
const nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true })
const accountName = 'insertaccountnamehere'
Nightmare({ show: false })
      .goto(`https://www.instagram.com/${accountName}`)
      // your turn
```

You would update some variable that keeps the newest post, check if it changed, and then send whatever you want: embed, link, so on.

Comment: thank you so much i didnt need the entire code i just needed a lead...